# Windows keep trying to download updates for Office 2013

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365

Windows 10 keeps trying to download updates for Microsoft Office 2013. Although, I have uninstalled Microsoft Office 2013 and currently am running the Office 2016. I have an Office 365 Account provided by my University.
 Windows updates keeps trying to update Office 2013, though, which I uninstalled, obviously it is failing every time. Downloading the updates works, installing the updates fails.
 How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Does this (http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-office-20162013-updates-also-office-365/) solve your problem?

Comment: @Schwesi but I want it to keep updating office 2016 though. Just stop looking for updates of uninstalled software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to  remove Microsoft Office 2013 for good.
Follow the instruction [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
Go to 'Option 2 - Completely uninstall Office with the easy fix tool' and click the download button to download the 'easy fix tool'. 
Otherwise you could think about uninstalling Microsoft Office althogether and then reinstalling Microsoft Office 2016.
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: But I see no trace in program files or app & features dialog in control panel regarding Office 2013

Comment: But I guess It falls down to remove everything office related and reinstall what I need

Comment: I guess that is faster than any other solution. Please let me know, if you keep having this problem afterwards.